# Org-mode: Make links clickable in column view?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I tried to make some org file to organize my thing in emacs, but I can't quite get how to make a clickable link in [column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-View.html).

Currently, my org file looks like this:

```
* Main
:PROPERTIES:
:COLUMNS: %10ITEM %20LINK
:END:
** SUB1
:PROPERTIES:
:LINK: [[foo][bar]]
:END:
** SUB2
:PROPERTIES:
:LINK: [[bar][foo]]
:END:
```

However, instead of clickable link, I got something like this in column view:

```
  ITEM     | LINK         |
* Main     |              |
** SUB1    |[[foo][bar]]  |
** SUB2    |[[bar][foo]]  |
```

Is there any way to make column view show a clickable link like elsewhere in Org mode?

Comment: I don't think this is supported.

Comment: that's too bad. Is it possible to implement myself ? (I have no prior experience in emacs-lisp but I think I could handle it.)

Comment: as far as I understand column view is implemented with text overlays. And considering that the links themselves are implemented as overlays in org-mode, it might be somewhat non-trivial. I would suggest you ask on the org-mode mailing list, the dev community is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did I misunderstand your problem or is there any sepecial org-mode configuration in your `.emacs.d`, I open your org-mode file with `emacs -Q`, and all links are clickable.

```sh
~ » emacs --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
GNU Emacs 28.0.91
```

[image]

Comment: On Emacs 30.0.50 with `emacs -Q` links are not clickable for me.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you are in fact using [column view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-View.html) in your gif.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether things were different back then, but in more recent Org mode versions (I'm on 9.6) this is quite easy to achieve.

There is already the command `org-columns-open-link`, which by default is bound to `C-c C-o` in column view, that does open links. Hence to make all links clickable one simply has to:

```lisp
(org-defkey org-columns-map [mouse-1] #'org-columns-open-link)
```

This will however show a user-error message whenever clicking on a non-link (e.g. to change point).

To get a nicer user experience one can instead customize `org-columns-modify-value-for-display-function` as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-column-display-value-transformer (column-title value)
  "Modifies the value to display in column view."
  (when (and (string-prefix-p "[[" value)
             (string-suffix-p "]]" value))
    (string-match org-link-bracket-re value)
    (let ((target (match-string 1 value))
          (descr (match-string 2 value)))
      (setq value (or descr target))
      ;; put the suitable faces:
      (put-text-property 0 (length value) 'face 'org-link value)
      (put-text-property 0 (length value) 'mouse-face 'highlight value)
      ;; help echo:
      (put-text-property 0 (length value) 'help-echo
                         (format "LINK: %s" target) value)
      ;; put a local keymap:
      (put-text-property 0 (length value) 'keymap
                         '(keymap (mouse-1 . org-columns-open-link)) value)
      value)))

(setq org-columns-modify-value-for-display-function
      #'my-column-display-value-transformer)
```

One can check whether the text properties at point are set as expected by exaluating `(get-char-property (point) 'org-columns-value)` in column view.

Answer (score 0):

Org mode 9.6.7

Searching for tags `xxx`, with links:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :id local :match "xxx" :format "%ITEM(Title) %ID(Link)"
| Title | Link |                  |
|-------+------+------------------|
| Help  | 7EB  | [[id:7EB][Link]] |
#+TBLFM: $3='(format "\[[id:%s][Link]\]" $2)
#+END: columnview
```